# Is there a way to have shared secrets between two Azure Key vaults?

Tags: azure, databricks, azure-databricks, azure-keyvault

As part of our data pipeline development my team maintains separate key vaults as scoped secret vaults for different regions of Azure Databricks. Now comes a situation where we need to maintain a specific configuration secret in both the Key Vaults and make sure that they are always in sync. **Is there a way to have a shared secret between 2 Azure Key vaults in same subscription apart from maintaining a CI/CD through the same repo?**

Below is sample illustration of how things are:

- Key vault 'KV-EUS' connects to Databricks instance 'DB-EUS' with the scope name of 'Scope-X'
- Key vault 'KV-WUS' connects to Databricks instance 'DB-WUS' with the scope name of 'Scope-X'

**Note:** I cannot change the design of the Key Vaults and Databricks connection, the reason I cannot attach 'KV-EUS' to 'DB-WUS' (or vice-versa) is because the code is written so that it expects the scope to be named 'Scope-X' in any Databricks instance. *These changes are doable but not in the given timeframe*

Comment: Perhaps create a separate key-vault that only contains shared secrets and keys that all apps talk to?

Comment: That's a possible solution but as of now that's not viable due to multiple constraints as stated in the 'Note'. Thanks for the thought though

Comment: you could use eventgrid trigger for key vault, whenever something is updated in your vault, you could run some scripts (function app / automation account) to sync to the second key vault https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-key-vault?tabs=event-grid-event-schema

Answer (score 2):

You could use a pipeline in Azure DevOps or an Azure Automation Runbook to run this [PowerShell code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/backup?tabs=powershell#back-up-and-restore-from-the-azure-cli-or-azure-powershell). Note that Key Vault backup and restore can happen cross region (e.g. East US to West US) but [not cross geography](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/backup?tabs=powershell#design-considerations) (e.g. US to Europe) so you should be fine in your scenario.

Comment: Thank you! Though I was not looking for a CI/CD solution but looks like at the moment that's the least disruptive way to get things done. Hope there is a hidden solution somewhere in Azure KV that allows us to share secrets between KVs natively. Just a hope!